# Problema com push e pull no github

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando fazer um `git pull` e um `git push` para enviar arquivos para o meu repositório no github mas em ambos os casos dá esse erro:

```
 error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Alguém sabe como solucionar esse problema?

Não sei se tem alguma relação mas eu instalei o Android Studio recentemente e agora o github não funciona.

OBS : Eu uso Windows 8.

**EDITADO :**

Eu atualizei o tanto o git quanto o Windows mas o erro continua. Aparentemente o erro tem a ver com a biblioteca openssl que o git usa. Eu instalei a openssl para Windows mas não resolveu o erro. Eu troquei as pastas (do openssl instalado com a que tem no git) mas também não resolveu.

Alguém sabe como atualizar essa biblioteca que é usada pelo git?

Comment: Você está usando a linha de comando do `git` ou alguma ferramenta em cima do `git`?

Comment: chegou a tentar [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944875/sourcetree-error1407742essl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1-alert-protoc)?

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa atualizar o `git` para a última versão https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Eu instalei a nova versão e tirei a outra do path. Ele pega a nova versão mas ainda continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Veja como esta as configurações  do git como a instrução via linha de comando: git config --global --list ... remova todas e  insira novamente, talvezes seja isso.

Answer (score -1):

Isso ocorre devido a uma descontinuação de alguns padrões criptográficos, fazendo parte da criptografia utilizada no tráfego de dados pelos protocolos obsoleta.

Caso atualizar a versão do git (mais recomendável) não resolva o problema, pode-se alterar a versão do protocolo `TLS` utilizado pelo git através do comando:

```
git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

[Referência](https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/).